# jQuery Mobile horizontal select - minimum width

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I can't figure out the CSS to give each select button a minimum or fixed width. By default the width adjusts to the content but I want to have a minimum. I have several rows and I want them to stay aligned as the selection changes.

There are similar questions for non-jqm select boxes where the solution is simply setting width attribute, but that doesn't work here.

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/btppS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the width of the label you have to change inside the css this line:

```
.ui-btn-text{
   width:300px; //example
}
```

Instead if you want to change the select when you click on it you can try this code with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#select-choice-month').css('width', '200px');//insert your width this is only for the month
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know *why* I couldn't figure that out. Mind you after mulling it over it might be better solved by making the fieldset 100% wide (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the $(document).ready(..) is not really the right place in JQMobile (see this good link of [Mark Dalgleish](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/04/document-ready-for-jquery-mobile/) ). But to answer to your question and becasue i have similar problem i used the "pagebeforeshow" event to do it because the "pagecreate" was not enough in the event tree in my case.

So i did something as:

```
$('div[data-role=page]').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){ 
    $('.ui-select .ui-btn-text').css({'width':'60px'});
});
```